# How to create directory in external storage?

Tags: java, android, file, directory

I want to create a directory in external storage but I am unable to create it.

This is my code:

```
 String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File dir = new File(path,"/appname/media/appimages/");
    if (!dir.isDirectory()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    File file = new File(dir, "image" + ".jpg");
    String imagePath =  file.getAbsolutePath();
    //scan the image so show up in album
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
            new String[] { imagePath }, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                }
            });


    File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/MeaVita");

    file1.mkdir();


    //  imageRoot.mkdirs();

    Log.d("directory",dir.getAbsolutePath().toString());
```

I tried both using mkdirs() and mkdir(). But neither of them work. I am unable to see the folder at the path storage/emulated/0/ .

I am running this on android 23.0 onwards also I have added the permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Does someone know what goes wrong in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try creating just one folder for starters.

Comment: Have you requested permission at real time, because with some permissions (like read and write) you need to that before you read or write to the storage

Answer (score 1):

With certain permissions you need to check at runtime if the users accepts them you can do it by creating a method like this:

```
private void checkFilePermissions() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int hasWriteExternalStoragePermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (hasWriteExternalStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it before you access your storage

Comment: this works.. Thank you.. But what if I don't want to let user know that I am going to access the storage? As I want to create a default folder of my app to store the images at start of app. So it will be confusing for the user as why this app needs permission now? @Dennis van Opstal

Comment: Also if I install app it dose not ask every time I install the app. Only once when I tried with debug it asked for the permission. I have called this method at start of startup activity in onCreate method. @Dennis van Opstal

Comment: I am not getting what's wrong. It's asking for permission when I do debug. But not when I run the app. Why so? @Dennis van Opstal

Comment: @Sid I'm not sure what goes wrong for you, it works on my end, so I don't know a solution to your problem, sorry :(

Comment: ok.. But is it a good approach to ask at the start of app? @Dennis van Opstal

Comment: @Sid I always ask it right before I need the permission and I think that is better, but I'm not entirely sure

Answer (score 0):

I checked it .. Its a permission issue .. quick solution to switch to 22 instead of 23. or you need to handle permissions on runtime see : [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)